# How do I overlay a modalViewController on top of another view without the original disappearing?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiviewcontroller

I want to show a customised alert panel over my app, but have the previous UIViewController visible in the background. I was hoping to show this as a modal view controller. How do I do this without the previous UIViewController turning black and disappearing?

Answer (score 17):

Instead of showing the new vc as a modal vc, you need to add it as child view controller:

```
AlertPanelVC *alertVC = ...
[self addChildViewController: alertVC];
alertVC.view.frame = ...; //or something equivalent if you're using auto layout 
[self.view addSubview: alertVC.view];
[alertVC didMoveToParentViewController: self];
```

To dismiss it:

```
[alertVC willMoveToParentViewController:nil];
[alertVC.view removeFromSuperview];
[alertVC removeFromParentViewController];
```

Comment: Excellent answer. I would add two modifications. (1) Instead of simple add and remove subview, you can animate. (2) You're going to want to block out user interaction with the outer part of the screen visible in the background. To do so, make the new view controller's view the same size as the screen, with a clear background where user interaction is disabled. The user can't see it (it's clear) but it blocks touches from falling thru. Your new interface is then a subview on top of *that*.

Comment: Agreed. Personally I like to use a black 'background view' with an alpha value of 0.5-0.8. That's creates the effect that the background darkens when the 'overlay' is shown. But that's just a personal preference. :)

Comment: Just tried adding `nil` as the fromViewController...got an error "'Children view controllers (null) and <SettingsViewController: 0xa9ec5a0> must have a common parent view controller when calling -[UIViewController transitionFromViewController:...'", so I don't think this will work.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I have used:

```
MyCustomAlertViewController *myCustomAlertViewController  = [[MyCustomAlertViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"MyCustomAlertViewController" bundle:nil];
myCustomAlertViewController.delegate = self;  //optional if you have delegate setup
[myCustomAlertViewController setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationPageSheet];
[myCustomAlertViewController setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal];
[self presentViewController:myCustomAlertViewController animated:YES completion:^{
    //do stuff after the view is displayed.

}];
myCustomAlertViewController.view.superview.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin;
myCustomAlertViewController.view.superview.frame = CGRectMake(calculatedCenterX, CalculatedCenterY, myCustomAlertViewControllerWidth, myCustomAlertViewControllerHeight);
//calculatedCenterX = (1024 - myCustomAlertViewControllerWidth) / 2;  //for example
//calculatedCenterY = (768 - myCustomAlertViewControllerHeight) / 2;
```

Comment: Correct, @Tobi - and original questioner used tag iPhone, not iPad.

Answer (score 0):

there is a [cool blurred](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/rnblurmodalview) component for that. of course ,just a matter of taste. :)

Answer (score 0):

> When presenting a view controller using the UIModalPresentationFullScreen style, UIKit normally removes the views of the underlying view controller after the transition animations finish. You can prevent the removal of those views by specifying the UIModalPresentationOverFullScreen style instead. You might use that style when the presented view controller has transparent areas that let underlying content show through.

[From here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/PresentingaViewController.html)

So basically instantiate your viewcontroller, specify the modal presenation style and then present the view controller.

If you want to have a (semi)transparent background, just adjust the color of the view controller's main view.